# SCP not willing to transfer remote to remote

Tags: ssh, scp, synchronization, nas

My family and I are attempting to sync all our data across multiple locations and devices. Seeing as we are just setting it up, we were wanting to start with the basics before building on it further, but are somehow already running into issues.

The setup I'm testing with currently is:

*Location A:*

1. 1x NAS (Synology DS214+)
2. 1x Raspberry Pi running Rasbian.

*Location B:*

1. 1x NAS (Synology DS214+)
2. 1x Raspberry Pi running Rasbian.

All of These devices are already connected to eachother through a VPN.
When attempting to run this command:

```
scp -v -3 admin@10.8.0.102:/volume1/pictures/ admin@10.8.0.103:/volume1/Backup/LocB/pictures
```

It will request a Password, that when filled in gives the following error:

```
admin@10.8.0.102's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

At first I thought it was a wrong password, but after muliple tries I have given up on this theory, mainly because:

When attempting to sync local data instead of remote/remote it does work. Both to and from Location A and Location B:

Respective commands are:

```
scp -v -3 pictures/ admin@10.8.0.102:/volume1/pictures/
```

and

```
scp -v -3 admin@10.8.0.103:/volume1/Backup/LocA/pictures/ pictures/
```

Both yielding something along the lines of:

```
admin@10.8.0.102's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 10.8.0.102 ([10.8.0.102]:22).
Sending file modes: C0644 66 test.txt
Sink: C0644 66 test.txt
test.txt                                                                              100%   66    57.9KB/s   00:00
Transferred: sent 2468, received 2892 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 32340.0, received 37896.0
```

Could someone please give me any insight how I can see what is going on? It doesn't seem to be a permission issue of writing/reading, nor a wrong Password.

Answer (score 0):

let's start by sshing into 10.8.0.102 and running

```
scp -v -3 /volume1/pictures/ admin@10.8.0.103:/volume1/Backup/LocB/pictures/
```

if this doesn't work then you need to add A's public key to B's ~/.ssh/known_hosts and vice versa.

also are you sure you want the entire directory to be copied or the contents of the directory?

did you mean to do this?

```
scp -v -3 -r /volume1/pictures/ admin@10.8.0.103:/volume1/Backup/LocB/pictures/
```

Comment: That command worked (with obviously the -r tag).

Comment: What was the problem with the authentication between point A and point B? The -r tag shouldn't have fixed that, strange.

Comment: If this is solved please this post as solved.